# How to properly add Red Bean PHP into my project

Tags: php, rest, slim, redbean, slim-3

I'm not very experienced with php projects structure, I found this awesome and simple tutorial: https://arjunphp.com/creating-restful-api-slim-framework/ how to create simple slim rest app.

This is actually PHP SLIM's official project structure, my question is what is best and proper way to add and use RedBean php ORM, I dont want on every route to include something like this

```
use \RedBeanPHP\R as R;
R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'myusername', 'mypassword)
```

and then

```
$book = R::load( 'book', $id );
```

And then use ReadBean for my db stuff. Im wondering how to include RedBeans into project and then just use it where i need it. This is my project structure https://github.com/iarjunphp/creating-restful-api-slim-framework3.

Note: i added red beans via composer like its described here https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean

Comment: If you're using Slim skeleton app, then dependencies.php is probably a good place to put set up code.

Comment: Can you maybe write some code sample of that so i can see how i should do it ?

Comment: You already wrote the code! The first block of code, the `use` statement and `R::setup` call Just move it to `src/dependencies.php`. Did you face any problems using your code that you decided to ask about it on SO? Your code seems fine.

Comment: i updated my question, as you can see i added everything to dependencies.php but in other file for example route.php i can not use red beans

Comment: Now you just need to add `use \RedBeanPHP\R as R;` to your routes.php as well. Only once, then you can use `R::load` inside your route callbacks.

Comment: Thx its working, i didnt know that i need to add use \RedBeanPHP\R as R; both in dependencies.php and routes.php. So can you confirm this is good structure. (i edited my quesiton)

Comment: The structure is fine now, but it is not a good idea to incorporate the solution in the question. Now your question is not a question anymore.

Comment: I know you should put answer so i can mark it as solution. Thx again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the code for setting up your libraries in any file that is going to be included on each request, so assuming you're using `slim/slim-skeleton`, `src/dependencies.php` is probably the place you want to add these two lines:

```
use \RedBeanPHP\R as R;
R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=njux_db', 'root', '');
```

Then you can use ReadBeans in your route callbacks but you also need to add the `use \RedBeanPHP\R as R;` statement to your `src/routes.php` as well (or any file that is going to use this class)

Comment: add "use \RedBeanPHP\R as R;" solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a MVC framework (which I recommend) like [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) it's pretty easy.

You only have to copy your `rb.php` to the `application/third_party` folder.

Then create a file called `application/libraries/rb.php` containing a code like this one.

```
<?php
class Rb { 
  function __construct()    {
    include(APPPATH.'/config/database.php');
    include(APPPATH.'/third_party/rb.php');
    $host = $db[$active_group]['hostname'];
    $user = $db[$active_group]['username'];
    $pass = $db[$active_group]['password'];
    $db   = $db[$active_group]['database'];
    R::setup("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass); 
   }
}
?>
```

...and vôila. RedBean will read your database configuration from CodeIgniter's standard file `application/config/database.php` and you will be able to use any `R::` command from anywhere in your code. No includes, not additional code required :-)